# Single data type for different variables

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, flowtype

Let's make this straight. I am a newbie in [Flow](https://flow.org). I want to declare single data type for different variables, like we do in `Java`.

```
public class Person {
    String name, nickName;
}
```

Current Code

```
// @flow
export default class Person {
    name : string;
    nickName : string;
}
```

What i want is something like this

```
// @flow
export default class Person {
    name, nickName : string;
}
```

One data type for different variables. Is this possible using `Flow`? . I've searched the web, read the official docs, but couldn't find anything positive.

Comment: Maybe you're talking about TS, you can do it using `TypeScript`

Comment: I need flow solution. Is it possible using `Flow` ? @WalterChapilliquen-wZVanG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible. That syntax is based on the upcoming [class fields proposal](https://tc39.github.io/proposal-class-fields/) which does not support such syntax. Here are the relevant production rules:

```
ClassElement:
  MethodDefinition
  static MethodDefinition
  FieldDefinition;
  ;

FieldDefinition:
  ClassElementName Initializeropt

ClassElementName:
  PropertyName

PropertyName:
  LiteralPropertyName
  ComputedPropertyName

 LiteralPropertyName:
  IdentifierName
  StringLiteral
  NumericLiteral

ComputedPropertyName:
  [AssignmentExpression]
```